# Needing to test European W/D combo equipped with 20A 250V

Tags: electrical, appliances

[image: plug]

Can an adapter to 15A 125v be used to test working condition of a European washer and dryer all in one until? Will that supply enough power to operate the machine temporarily?

Comment: Generally not. The frequency is wrong, motors will typically run too fast, electronics may not tolerate it either.

Comment: Can you clarify?  The subject is about a European appliance, with a picture of an American 240V plug  but the question is about an "adapter".  Three different things and no explanation of how they relate.  And if you have some kind of adapter you should please provide more detail about that.

Answer (score 1):

No way. Electricity serves us, but it doesn't serve us *magically*. The right things must be connected the right way.

If I saw a European appliance with the pictured NEMA 6-15 plug, I wouldn't blink an eye.  There is nothing wrong with that.  NEMA 6-15 is specifically made for 240V appliances in the range of common Euro appliances (which themselves feed from a 13A or 16A breaker).

What doesn't work is your aspiration to plug that into the universally common, "everywhere in America" NEMA ***5***-15 receptacle which you have easy access to.  It doesn't matter how common they are: they simply won't work on a 240V load.  You should not attempt to plug a NEMA 6-15 into a 5-15.

If you need to do it "temporarily", you have two options:

- Temporarily use a 240V generator.  This is any consumer tier generator bigger than about 4000 watts.  (the smallest don't offer 240V). The 240V socket on it probably will not be NEMA 6-15 (6-20 also works), so you would need an adapter cable, or change the plug end on that cord.
- Temporarily use an adapter cable to adapt a 6-15 or 6-20 from another NEMA 6 or NEMA 14 socket as you might have in your home, e.g. for dryer.
- Have an electrician "temporarily" install a 240V circuit wired to a NEMA 6-15 socket.

The various socket types:

[image]

Comment: Could also temporarily adapt down from a NEMA 14-30 or 14-50 (using the same adapter as would be used for the 240V sockets on larger generators)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Good point... added.

Answer (score 0):

A 120V "converter" to power that would need to have a 40A input, and you're not going to find one in any normal house. 240V circuits are a lot easier to find in most US houses, as those are actually used (for electric ranges, dryers, welders, etc...)

A 15A 120V input can power, at most, 7.5A at 240V.

a 120V 40A circuit is used for - pretty much nothing. Even a 30A 120V circuit is rare, and normally only seen (but rarely) in industrial locations.

Comment: The only place I've ever seen 30A@120V used is in smaller RV travel trailers.

Comment: I get them as supplies for "slightly bigger than consumer grade" 120V UPSes. The computers all use normal 5-15 plugs. Sometimes they are wired with an L5-20 instead of an L5-30 so we need an electrician callback to sort it out (oddly, this error occurs without the breaker bing a 20 instead of a 30 most of the times I've seen it. But the plug sure doesn't fit.)